# Question on Group Isomorphism Dihedral group

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

Let $ D_6 = \{ e, r, r^2,f,rf,r^2f \} $ be the dihedral group of order $ 6 $ (Recall that we have the  following relations: $ r^3=e, f^2=e $ and $ fr^i=f^{3-i}r $ for $ i=1,2 $).

Suppose that $ G=\{ u,v,w,x,y,z \} $ is a group with operation $ * $ where $ z $ has order $ 3 $, $ y * z=u $ and $ v * w =y $. Suppose that we have the isomorphism

$ \phi(f)=v, \phi(rf)=w $. Find $ \phi(r) $ and $ \phi(r^2) $.

My answer:

$ \phi(rf). \phi(f)=\phi(rf^2)=\phi(r). $

So, $ w * v= \phi(r) $. And, $ \phi(r^2) = \phi(r). \phi(r)=(w*v)*(w*v)=w*y*v $.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure $fr^i=f^{3-i}r$ is correct? (as we have $fr=f^2r$ and $fr^2=fr$)

Comment: That is what's given in the question. I thought there is something wrong with that as well but wasn't sure.

Comment: I think $fr^i=f^{3-i}r$ should be $fr^i=r^{3-i}f$. This is the correct rule for dihedral groups.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $frf=r^2ff=r^2$ so $\phi(r^2)=v\ast w=y$. As $|z|=3$ this forces $\phi(r)=z$.